# MySql query doesnt display results

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

I have a string with values like:
a,b,c,d,e

The idea is to use an sql command to search an array for entries.
The sql is:

```
select * from pelates where Onoma in (@giorti)
```

I am turning the a,b,c,d,e to 'a','b','c','d','e' an then i replace the @giorti value with the previus string to fill a datagridview.
The problem is that the datagridview stays empty unless i edit the sql statement and give a value manually like:

```
select * from pelates where Onoma in ('Bampis')
```

if i do so the results come like normal. Please advice ,i think there an encoding problem because the data are in Greek
Here is my code:

```
 //Diaxorismos onomaton pou giortazoun

        String giorti = label2.Text;
        String[] name = giorti.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name[i]);
            sb.Insert(0, "'");
            sb.Append("'");
            name[i] = sb.ToString();
            name[i] = name[i];
        }

        String finalName = String.Join(",", name);
        finalName = finalName.Replace(" ", "");
        textBox1.Text = finalName;
        //


        showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand = login.connection.CreateCommand();
        showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand.CommandText = "select * from pelates where Onoma in (@giorti)";
        showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@giorti", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(finalName));
        getPelatesPouGiortazounAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand);
        pelatesPouGiortazounDataset = new DataSet();
        getPelatesPouGiortazounAdapter.Fill(pelatesPouGiortazounDataset);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = pelatesPouGiortazounDataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FIND_IN_SET function to search in a comma separated list,
or prepare and bind as many parameters as you have values in the string.

```
select * from pelates where FIND_IN_SET(Onoma, @giorti)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot fellows!
With the above addition my code works great!
Here is the final code:

```
 String giorti = label2.Text;
        String[] name = giorti.Split(',');
        String finalName = label2.Text;
        finalName = finalName.Replace(" ", "");
        textBox1.Text = finalName;

        showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand = login.connection.CreateCommand();
        showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand.CommandText = "select * from pelates where FIND_IN_SET(Onoma, @giorti)";
        showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@giorti", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(finalName));
        getPelatesPouGiortazounAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(showPelatesPouGiortazounCommand);
        pelatesPouGiortazounDataset = new DataSet();
        getPelatesPouGiortazounAdapter.Fill(pelatesPouGiortazounDataset);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = pelatesPouGiortazounDataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```